# can a geometric sequence have ratio if 1

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometric-series

Can a geometric sequence have common ratio of $1$?
(eg: $2,2,2,2,2,...$)

it follows the rule $b^2 = ac$. So, I think it is also a geometric progression.

But the sum formula is $\frac{a(r^{n}-1)}{(r-1)}$ and when $r=1$ , denominator gets zero. Hence, I got this doubt.

I know the formula is when $r>1$ or $r<1$. but why it is not defined for $r=1$. Is it because when $r=1$, it is not a GP?

Please help. thanks

Comment: Yes, you can have a geometric sequence with ratio of $1$. In that case you have another sum formula, ie. $S(n)=n \cdot 2$ (assuming you are numering from $1$)

Comment: thanks @luka5z. But see https://people.richland.edu/james/lecture/m116/sequences/geometric.html . it is given there as "The magnitude of the ratio can't equal one because that the series wouldn't be geometric" . so is this wrong?

Comment: @Jay, we have formula for sum of n terms when common ratio > 1 right? similarly, why we don't have a formula for sum of n terms when common ratio = 1?

Comment: @Kiran When you have a geometric sequence of the form $a+ar+ar^2+ \text{...}$ and set $r=1$ then you just have a sum of $n$ $a$'s so the sum is just $na$.

Comment: @Kiran so technically it's still a geometric series just a boring case of one since $r=1$. Similarly it's an arithmetic series with the common difference being $0$.

Comment: thanks jay, it is clear now. thanks

Comment: @Kiran No problem, glad to help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A geometric sequence $u_n$ is a sequence which is defined recursively by (given $u_1$)

$$u_{n+1}=ru_n,\quad r\in \Bbb R $$
where the ratio $r$ is a given number. The sum formula is
$$\sum_{k=1}^nu_k=u_1\frac{1-r^n}{1-r},\;\text{if}\, r\ne1$$
and
$$\sum_{k=1}^nu_k=nu_1,\;\text{if}\, r=1$$